# Создание сайта

Tags: html

Вот создал я страничку и задал размер изображениям и прочее. Но у всех разное расширение монитора и при просмотре может получится совсем не то, что я задумал. Как с этим бороться? Спасибо.

Comment: Простите,а где здесь ставить галочку?) Классный сервис, сразу столько ответов на вопрос) и все по делу

Comment: слева сверху возле правильного ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем вопросе таится ответ... Когда вы задаете фиксированные размеры изображению, это и значит, что во всех браузерах, вне зависимости от разрешения экрана картинка будет отображаться указанного размера. Ну а если обобщить, то почитайте про резиновую верстку.

Comment: Ну например у меня высокое расширение и картинка занимает пол монитора, а у кого то низкое, и она не влезет в монитор грубо говоря...

Comment: вы можете с легкостью посмотреть, как ваш сайт будет выглядеть на разных разрешениях, просто уменьшая окно браузера. плюс можно указывать размеры в процентах а не в пикселях.

Comment: это да... но с fixed елементами так лучше не делать т.к. и посидеть можно :)

Comment: ну fixed элементы вообще туго сочетаются с резиновой версткой..

Answer (score 1):

[Оптимальная ширина веб-страницы](http://www.neobiznes.ru/articles/view/Optimalnaja_shirina_veb-stranicy)

Зачем лисапед?

Comment: солидарен на все 100%<br>
`body {
   width:1200px;
   margin:auto;
}`<br>И будет вам благодать...

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант предлагаю для фотографий создать механизм на javascript или php (или связка), который бы определял разрешения монитора у пользователя и подгружал бы нужный файл с нужным размером.

Типа если разрешение по ширине меньше или равно 1024, то грузим в нужный див файл такой-то,
если разрешение больше или равно 1200, то грузим другой файл.

Я знаю, так можно делать, но код не смогу вам дать, так как плохой я программист. )

Comment: вот, об этом я не знал, спасибо)

Comment: этот вариант не всегда оправдан. проще элементу img задавать height и width

Comment: читсо javascript'ом делается, зачем тут php непонятно...

Comment: все я решил) лучшее что можно сделать - это указывать размер в процентах) только надо какую то табличку что бы вычислять проценты)

Comment: зачем табличка?

Comment: что бы быстро выщитывать нужный процент и не нарушать пропорции)

Comment: php мне думается нужен для.... в общем я что там про ajax думал

Comment: установите, плагин firebug на браузер, это позволит вам в режиме реального времени изменять размеры и видеть результат. что существенно упростит верстку. и не забывайте ставить галочку если получили ответ на свой вопрос )

Comment: сорри я вспомнил что когда задешь процентное соотношение то это влияет на ширину и высоту одновременно, табличка не нужна)

Comment: php исполняется на стороне сервера и в вашей ситуации он совершенно не нужен. и как вы вернозаметили, css здесь, не просто лучше, а даже необходим.